# How to attach an UI button to a prefab and follow it in Unity2D

Tags: unity, gui

My plan is creating a button above my prefab (a tree) and whenever my character is detected, the button will appear and allow me to click on it to active a dialog. I just want my trees are randomly spawned and stay still so it's not "follow" actually but I would like to know in that case too.

I did some researches but most of them were about Text and HP/MP things, which weren't used by UI system.

One more thing, I kinda new to code so it would be fantastic if I got a full code (Button follow only).

Thanks in advanced.